# Is it possible to write multiple blobs in a single request?

Tags: azure-blob-storage

We're planning to use Azure blob storage to save processing log data for later analysis. Our systems are generating roughly 2000 events per minute, and each "event" is a json document. Looking at the pricing for blob storage, the sheer number of write operations would cost us tons of money if we take each event and simply write it to a blob.

My question is: Is it possible to create multiple blobs in a single write operation, or should I instead plan to create blobs containing multiple event data items (for example, one blob for each minute's worth of data)?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible ,but isn't good practice ,it take long times to multipart files to be merge, hence we are trying to separate upload action from entity persist operation by passing entity id and update doc[image] name in other controller
Also it keeps you clean upload functionality .Best Wish

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to create multiple blobs in a single write operation.

One feasible solution is to create blobs containing multiple event data items as you planned (which is hard to implement and query in my opinion); another solution is to store the event data into Azure Storage Table rather than Blob, and leverage [EntityGroupTransaction](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-tables/#insert-a-batch-of-entities) to write table entities in one batch (which is billed as one transaction).

Please note that all table entities in one batch must have the same partition key, which should be considered when you're designing your table (see [Azure Storage Table Design Guide](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-table-design-guide/) for further information). If some of your events have large data size that exceeds the size limitation of Azure Storage Table (1MB per entity, 4MB per batch), you can save data of those events to Blob and store the blob links in Azure Storage Table.